# ER_PARSE_ERROR on sql file

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to execute sql queries from a file in nodejs.

This is the (summarized) code:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var mysql = require("mysql");

fs.readFile("path/to/my.sql", function(error, query) {
    mysql.connect(configuration, function(error, connection) {
        connection.query(query.toString(), callback); // this doesn't work
    }
}
```

Upon execution, following error is passed to my callback function:

```
{"code":"ER_PARSE_ERROR","index":0}
```

I have verified that:

- I can connect to the mysql host
- I can execute inline queries
- I can execute the file in mysql workbench
- I can open the file in node.js and log it to the console

Comment: Did you get solution for this? I have also facing this kind of problem. I have run following query very well in workbench, but throwing error "ER_PARSE_ERROR" while executing from node.js code. here is my query. SET [@loginid] = 6389163; SET @sysinfoid = null;
CALL usp_loginhistory([@loginid], [@sysinfoid]);